# A function similar to (>>=) but which returns a different monad

Tags: haskell, monads

The type of `(>>=)` is

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

I want a function that has the type:

```
(Monad m, Monad n) => m a -> (a -> n b) -> n b
```

This function could be used to chain different monads together.

I faced this problem when I was trying to get `3000` from the command-line arguments `-p 3000`:

```
main = getArgs >>= (\args -> (elemIndex "-p" args) >>= (\id -> warpDebug (fromIntegral.read (args !! (id+1))) Ilm))
```

This clearly won't compile because `getArgs` returns an `IO [String]` and `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int`. A function of the above type could be used to elegantly solve this problem. My question is:

- Is this function already defined? ([Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=m+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+n+b%29+-%3E+n+b) does not find any)
- If there isn't, it's probably due to some reason. What is the reason then? Is this considered a bad practice? I think it's a better way than having to use a case expression.

Answer (score 21):

Such a function doesn't exist. In fact, if you take `n` to be the identity monad, it would allow you to construct a function `m a -> a`, which clearly cannot be defined for all monads.

To address the general problem of "composing" two monads, you can look into [monad transformers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer).

However, it seems overkill to use monad transformers in your example. You can simply define a function `[String] -> Maybe Args` (for some custom type `Args` - say `Int` in the example) which does the command line argument processing, then pattern match on the result (or use [`maybe`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html#v%3amaybe)) from within the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 6):

This function doesn't exist because it would not make sense for all monads. It is basically equivalent to a monad unpacking function `Monad m => m a -> a`--the only difference is that you  immediately put it into another monad.

The reason this function is not defined for all monads is because it does not make sense for some of them. For example, take `Maybe`: the only way to unpack it would be to throw an error if you have `Nothing`, and runtime errors are looked down upon. A more extreme example would be `IO`--using a function that could "unpack" `IO` values would lead to weird and potentially nondeterministic behavior.

Thus, you do not have such a function in general. However, a lot of specific monads *do* come with such functions. A great example is `runST`; this is actually a safe way for dealing with state. You actually *do* have such functions for both `Maybe` and `IO` (`fromJust` and `unsafePerformIO` respectively), but they have the problems I outlined above and you should avoid them.

The solution to your problem, then, is to see if there exists such a function for whichever monads you're dealing with. If there does, check any potential pitfalls--does it generate runtime errors or cause weird behavior?

In your case, if you are *absolutely* sure that the `Maybe` is never `Nothing`, use `fromJust`. However, this is not generally good practice, so you should just stick to pattern matching the value out of the `Maybe`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you need to use Maybe and IO monads together or separately.

If you need to use them together - the answer is that you need to compose `IO` and `Maybe` monads by constructing a stack of monad transformers containing IO monad and MaybeT monad transformer.

If you need them separately, then a simpler solution works:

```
import System.Environment
import Data.List

main = getArgs >>= (\args -> return (elemIndex "-p" args 
    >>= \y -> return $ y + 900) >>= print)
```

Note the `return`. So you have `Maybe` monad in the inner parentneses (between `elemIndex` and `900`), but not IO. That is, you cannot perform IO actions before leaving `Maybe` monad, as I showed with print.